# How can Eclipse resolve dependencies from Artifactory

Tags: eclipse, maven, artifactory

I have lot of JAR Files which are needed for our development. These libraries are included in Eclipse in every project.

These dependencies are copied every time.

I create a Maven repository in JFrog Artifactory and moved it to them.

I want to know how I can make Eclipse resolve dependencies from Artifactory and download them local for development.

I'm also quite new to Maven and still trying to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

You create a pom.xml in your project, add the dependencies, add your Artifactory to your settings.xml (in .m2 repository) and then start a Maven build.